# Do i need to use github and git same time?

Tags: github

Basically, I have gitbase and github at the same time. Is it efficient to use both?

Giving some hint will be perfect. Although I just started using git, there are so many things I don't know about it. like some time I cannot use commend poperly.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to. You can use Git to control the files and push files into Github. For example, if you want to add a repository using Git you can do that. It'll help you to learn Git controls more so that in future you can do open source contribution to other repositories.